# How to get validation errors in custom form control component

Tags: angular

I want to make a reusable input. The problem is that I don't know how to pass `Validation.errors` to a new component from an external component. The problem is also the status of `FormControl` - it is always `valid`. I attach the link to the stackblitz. I marked in red the part that I don't know how to solve.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evbk9q?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You need take account that you has two FormControl: the FormControl that you create in app.component -who is the FormControl that has the error- and the "inner" FormControl -the formControl that you use as auxiliar in your custom-input.component

So you need "get" the FormControl in app.component from your custom -input.

You can get the "ngControl" of your control. There're three ways

1.-inject in constructor Inject and in ngOnInit of your custom-input to have some like

```
ngControl:NgControl
constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.ngControl = injector.get(NgControl);
    ....rest of your code..
}
ngOnInit()
{
    this.ngControl = injector.get(NgControl);
}
```

2.- Remove the two providers and inject directly the ngControl -but you loose the "validation"

```
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
      if (!!ngControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
      }
      ...
  }
```

So we can use

```
<div style="color: red;">
  value: {{ ngControl.control.value | json }}
  <br />
  errors: {{ ngControl.control.errors | json }}
  <br />
 valid:  {{ ngControl.control.valid | json }}
</div>
```

3.- The third way is, as we have a validate function, we can get the control (not the ngControl) in this function

```
  control:FormControl=null

  validate(control: FormControl) {
    if (!this.control)
      this.control=control
    return this.formControl.valid ? null : { profile: { valid: false } };
  }
```

And we can write

```
<div style="color: red;">
  value: {{ control.value | json }}
  <br />
  errors: {{ control.errors | json }}
  <br />
 valid:  {{ control.valid | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: 1st approach works. for more fine grained differentiation between `FormControlName` and `FormControl` as result of `injector.get(NgControl)` please see https://medium.com/@toha.marko/get-actual-control-in-controlvalueaccessor-e5bb3bb6710

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameter for your component as:

```
<app-custom-input
    [isValid]="formGroup.get('input')?.valid"
    formControlName="input">
</app-custom-input>
```

and in your component:

```
@Input() isValid : boolean;
```

So `isValid` prop contains info about form input is valid or not.

Comment: the idea is get the `formGroup.get('input')` from the custom-input, not passing as Input